# Finding Server-side Functionality in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, server-side, server-side-scripting

Allow me to preface this by saying I know absolutely nothing about any version of ASP. I have been coding web pages off and on since the HTML3 days, but until last month (when I inherited a site written in ASP.NET), I’ve never even *seen* any ASP code, let alone needed to change it. So, this is absolutely a n00b question. Please don’t laugh too hard.

I need to change the email address on our company’s contact page, which I assume is really simple, but I can’t figure out where it’s stored. My only hint is a line of code that reads:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

Obviously, it’s saying that the Submit button runs some server-side code, but I don’t have the slightest idea where to find it. I’d contact the company that wrote the code in the first place, but they seem to be out of business, so that’s a bust. Is there a standard location where I should be looking for the server-side code? If not, is there at least someplace I should start my search?

Thanks so much!

Comment: there should be an event handler method, `OnClick` IIRC

Comment: If you don't have the source but only a compiled library it's gonna be difficult. Unless it is stored in the `web.config` as an `AppSetting`